# How to I passing parameter using pagecontainer using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How do I make passing a parameter to the detail page using `$.mobile.pageContainer` ?

My code :

```
$(document).on("click", "ul#list_data_utama li" ,function (event) {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#detail");
});
```

Up here I have managed the page transition and call `div#detail`, but I want when the detail page is displayed, I would like to do a query to the server based on the `id` from `$(this).attr('id')` that I brought from previous page.

Thanks

Comment: You want to pass param to next page or to server upon changing page?

Comment: @Omar Yes..But I have to solve it yourself by using : `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#detail_utama", dataUrl=id);`